# How to display in Unity an exported GMenu in DBus?

Tags: unity, dbus

I can see exported menus with D-Feet but Unity doesn't display them... Any Idea, additional documentation or code examples?

This is my code:

```
GMenu *menu = g_menu_new ();
g_menu_append (menu, "Add", "app.add");
g_menu_append (menu, "Del", "app.del");
g_menu_append (menu, "Quit", "app.quit");

GDBusConnection *bus = g_bus_get_sync (G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, NULL, NULL);

guint id = g_dbus_connection_export_menu_model (bus, "/org/gtk/example/menus/AppMenu", G_MENU_MODEL (menubar), NULL);

g_object_unref (menu);
```

I won't use gtk_application_set_app_menu or libdbusmenu.

https://live.gnome.org/GTK%2B/GApplication-dbus-apis

Answer (score 1):

Missed some XSettings

```
GdkWindow *gdkwindow = gtk_widget_get_window (GTK_WIDGET (window));
gdk_x11_window_set_utf8_property (gdkwindow, "_GTK_UNIQUE_BUS_NAME", "org.gtk.example");
gdk_x11_window_set_utf8_property (gdkwindow, "_GTK_APP_MENU_OBJECT_PATH", "/org/gtk/example/menus/appmenu");
```